# Not able to toggle the PrimeFaces tree checkbox by clicking the node text?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem with PrimeFaces JSF UI library `tree` component:

```
<p:tree selectionMode="checkbox" ... >
```

The problem is: the checkbox can only be toggled by clicking on a checkbox directly. I would like to toggle checkbox by clicking on **node text**.

I looked at [PrimeFaces Labs](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/treeSelectionCheckbox.jsf), but there I see it works ok!

What am I missing, why am I not able to toggle the tree checkbox by clicking the node text?

Using version 3.4.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On showcase labs (link that you provided) this works fine because that is a version 3.5-SNAPSHOT, but if you take a look at [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeSelectionCheckbox.jsf) this works as in your code. So, they implemented that in current SHAPSHOT version, and it will be available in next release, or you can download 3.5-SNAPSHOT version and use it, but be prepared that there are some potential bugs not yet fixed.

You have a version of showcase at the bottom of the page.